# How to initialize preference page fields using ISecurePreferences?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to use ISecurePreferences instead of normal IPreferenceStore and the problem occurs when I'm trying to update the fields with stored values.

I don't find a method other than performOk, performApply, performDefaults, performCancel, and performHelp that runs in the UI thread in order to update the fields with the stored values.

Currently I'm doing this using asyncExec once I create the fields.

CODE:

```
@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    usernameField = new StringFieldEditor("username","Username:",getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(usernameField);
    //Create password field
    passwordField = new StringFieldEditor("password","Password:",getFieldEditorParent()){
        @Override
        protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {
            super.doFillIntoGrid(parent, numColumns);
            getTextControl().setEchoChar('*');
        }
    };      
    addField(passwordField);    
    try{
    ISecurePreferences root = SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault();
    final ISecurePreferences node = root.node("nodeName");

    System.out.println("Username initialized: "+node.get("username",""));
    System.out.println("Password initialized: "+node.get("password",""));


    Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                usernameField.setStringValue(node.get("username", ""));
                passwordField.setStringValue(node.get("password", ""));
            } catch (StorageException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    });                     
    }
    catch(StorageException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception storage...");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a correct solution in order to update the created fields. Is there a method which runs in UI thread and is called after createFieldEditors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field editors don't support `ISecurePreferences`. They will try and load and save the preference values in the normal preference store which may cause errors (especially if you have not set one).

So using field editors is not gaining you anything. It is probably simpler just to use an ordinary preference page rather than a field editor preference page and use normal controls like `Text`, `Button`, ....